# Dynamically traversing a deep nested object and accumulating results

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, traversal

Im trying to dissect a deeply nested object. Traversing it and pulling data to a single level object which then gets married up with a larger object down the line. I am able to traverse it with the following code but its not dynamic. As in, this only works if I know its 4 objects deep. Where in reality it can be 1 -> n deep. I also have a function that checks the type of value at that level and does work on it accordingly. Right now this works for me

```js
    run();
function run() {
  const topLevelObjects = [{
      field: 'pivotvalue0',
      value: '111111111',
      count: 36,
      pivot: [{
          field: 'pivotvalue1',
          value: 'Y',
          count: 27,
          pivot: [{
            field: 'pivotvalue2',
            value: 'Header1',
            count: 27,
            pivot: [{
                field: 'pivotvalue3',
                value: 'Value1',
                count: 14
              },
              {
                field: 'pivotvalue3',
                value: 'Value2',
                count: 13
              }
            ]
          }]
        },
        {
          field: 'pivotvalue1',
          value: 'Z',
          count: 9,
          pivot: [{
            field: 'pivotvalue2',
            value: 'Header2',
            count: 9,
            pivot: [{
              field: 'pivotvalue3',
              value: 'Value1',
              count: 9
            }]
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      field: 'pivotvalue0',
      value: '222222222',
      count: 23,
      pivot: [{
        field: 'pivotvalue1',
        value: 'Y',
        count: 23,
        pivot: [{
            field: 'pivotvalue2',
            value: 'Header1',
            count: 12,
            pivot: [{
              field: 'pivotvalue3',
              value: 'Value2',
              count: 12
            }]
          },
          {
            field: 'pivotvalue2',
            value: 'Header2',
            count: 11,
            pivot: [{
              field: 'pivotvalue3',
              value: 'Value2',
              count: 11
            }]
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]

  //pivotResponse.facet_counts.facet_pivot[pivotsString]
  const accumulatedPivotInfo = []
  //This is assuming you can only pivot 4 deep. Would love to figure out how to make this dynamic.
  for (const level0 of topLevelObjects) {
    let newPivotInfo = {}

    newPivotInfo[level0.field] = level0.value
    if (level0.pivot) {
      for (const level1 of level0.pivot) {
        newPivotInfo = {
          ...newPivotInfo,
          ...buildBasedOnType(level1, newPivotInfo)
        }
        if (level1.pivot) {
          for (const level2 of level1.pivot) {
            newPivotInfo = {
              ...newPivotInfo,
              ...buildBasedOnType(level2, newPivotInfo)
            }
            if (level2.pivot) {
              for (const level3 of level2.pivot) {
                newPivotInfo = {
                  ...newPivotInfo,
                  ...buildBasedOnType(level3, newPivotInfo)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    accumulatedPivotInfo.push(newPivotInfo)

  }
  console.log(accumulatedPivotInfo)
}

function buildBasedOnType(level, newPivotInfo) {
  if (level.field === 'pivotvalue1') {
    level.value === 'Y' ? newPivotInfo['pivotvalue1.1'] = level.count : newPivotInfo['pivotvalue1.1'] = 0
    level.value === 'N' ? newPivotInfo['pivotvalue1.2'] = level.count : newPivotInfo['pivotvalue1.2'] = 0
    level.value === 'Z' ? newPivotInfo['pivotvalue1.3'] = level.count : newPivotInfo['pivotvalue1.3'] = 0
  } else if (level.field === 'pivotvalue2' || level.field === 'pivotvalue3') {
    newPivotInfo[level.field + 's'] === undefined ? newPivotInfo[level.field + 's'] = new Set([level.value]) : newPivotInfo[level.field + 's'].add(level.value)
  } else {
    newPivotInfo[level.field] = level.value
  }
  return newPivotInfo
}
```

---

Here is what my final output looks like and what im trying to achieve

```
pivotInfo = [
  {
    pivotvalue0: '111111111',
    'pivotvalue1.1': 0,
    'pivotvalue1.2': 0,
    'pivotvalue1.3': 9,
    pivotvalue2s: Set { 'Header1', 'Header2' },
    pivotvalue3s: Set { 'Value1', 'Value2' }
  },
  {
    pivotvalue0: '222222222',
    'pivotvalue1.1': 23,
    'pivotvalue1.2': 0,
    'pivotvalue1.3': 0,
    pivotvalue2s: Set { 'Header1', 'Header2' },
    pivotvalue3s: Set { 'Value2' }
  }
]
```

For some reason the code runner does work with sets well. So here is the same code in jsfiddle that sets the sets: https://jsfiddle.net/x9sa8tqm/

Hopefully this is enough context to see what Im currently doing. Right now I have data to know how deep these objects will be via an array of values. So I can check the array length and know how deep I need to go. What would be the best way to make this dynamic? So it will flex to 'n' deepness instead of a head coded 4.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard about recursion?

Comment: It would help if you could give us a sample input structure (5 - 10 nodes, perhaps) in a single piece and the corresponding expected output. It's hard to suggest something when we don't have an explicit input, have no output and we're left guessing what `buildBasedOnType` actually does.

Comment: Sure give me a second. I will try to give more context

Comment: added entire input object along with my current outcome

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still confused.  I can't see how the output is connected to the input, and I don't really understand how `buildBasedOnType` works, as it is testing on values `myField1`, `myField2` and `myField3`, which don't appear in the input at all.

Comment: sorry I have  renamed some info to keep the data vague. I will try to take another pass at cleaning it up. Its not a huge priority since my current solution 'works'. Im just looking for a more dynamic way so future code will work. Thank you for you time so far! I will update soon^tm

Comment: Any update on this?  I'm curious to see what might work well.

Comment: I will try to get it updated today - I will for sure update it *sometime*. I  have primary work to finish this sprint. This is just something that is bothering me that i want to make better.

Comment: I updated my code. I actually just took my input and ran it through my function and copied its output. Hopefully the data matches up @ScottSauyet

Comment: I understand now what the code does, and can write [a different version](https://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/3nwaop56/) to generate your output.  But it's not clear to me how you want to make this more dynamic.  You have different behavior for `pivotvalue0` and `pivotvalue1`, and a third (shared) one for `pivotvalue2` and `pivotvalue3`.  What would be the behavior for `4`, `5`, `6`, or `42`?  Is everything from `2` up supposed to have the same behavior?  If not, what's the rule?

Comment: The default behavior is seen in the business logic function buildBasedOnType() ie   
 else {
    newPivotInfo[level.field] = level.value
  } 
There are some particular behavior i need to catch - which i do and catch in my 2 other ifs in those. The order in which these can come is irrelevant. Otherwise I just wanna take the value of that 'level' and put it assigned to its 'field'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Recursion to achieve this.

```js
var data = [
    {
      field: 'pivotvalue0',
      value: '200275399',
      count: 36,
      pivot: [{
      field: 'pivotvalue0.1',
      value: '200275399',
      count: 36,
      pivot: [{
      field: 'pivotvalue0.2',
      value: '200275399',
      count: 36,
      pivot: []
    }]
    }]
    },
    {
      field: 'pivotvalue0',
      value: '200746617',
      count: 23,
      pivot: []
    }
  ]

var finalResult = [];

function accumulateValue(data){
  data.forEach(item=>{
    finalResult.push({
      field: item.field,
      value: item.value,
      count: item.count,
    });
    if(item.pivot && item.pivot.length){
      accumulateValue(item.pivot)
    }
  })
}

accumulateValue(data)

console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: This gets me close. I am trying to modify it to exactly what I need. Essentially I need everything accumulated to 1 object - then those objects pushed to an array. I will update my question with what my current output is and some more datapoints.

Comment: i updated my question with the entire data input. along with my current expected output

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern can you please update the exact output you need based on the input example you have given(also if you could explain the output example)

Comment: yep i still plan to. sorry got caught up on some other things. Thank you for your patience

Comment: I updated my code. I actually just took my input and ran it through my function and copied its output. Hopefully the data matches up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that does this recursively.  We special-case the types you want to handle specifically, and for the all other cases, we add `{[field]: value}` to our running output object.

The main thing to note is that the recursion is automated.  We don't manually code the levels and this should let us go arbitrarily deep.

```js
// utility function
const gather = (prop) => (fn) => (o) => 
  [... fn (o), ... (prop in o ? o [prop] : []) .flatMap (gather (prop) (fn))]

// helper function
const collectField = (name) => (o) => ({
  [name + 's'] : 
    [... // comment out to get an actual set
      new Set(
        gather ('pivot') (
          ({field, value}) => field == name ? [value] : []
        ) (o)
      )
    ]  // comment out to get an actual set
})

// main function
const convert = (xs) => 
  xs .map ((x, _, __, {field, value, count, pivot = []} = x) => Object .assign ({
    ...(
      field == 'pivotvalue1'
        ? {
            'pivotvalue1.1': value == 'Y' ? count: 0,
            'pivotvalue1.2': value == 'N' ? count: 0,
            'pivotvalue1.3': value == 'Z' ? count: 0,
          }
      : field == 'pivotvalue2' || field == 'pivotvalue3'
        ? {}
      : {[field]: value}
    )}, 
    ... convert (pivot),
    collectField ('pivotvalue2') (x),                                                             
    collectField ('pivotvalue3') (x),                
  ))

// sample data
const topLevelObjects = [{field: "pivotvalue0", value: "111111111", count: 36, pivot: [{field: "pivotvalue1", value: "Y", count: 27, pivot: [{field: "pivotvalue2", value: "Header1", count: 27, pivot: [{field: "pivotvalue3", value: "Value1", count: 14}, {field: "pivotvalue3", value: "Value2", count: 13}]}]}, {field: "pivotvalue1", value: "Z", count: 9, pivot: [{field: "pivotvalue2", value: "Header2", count: 9, pivot: [{field: "pivotvalue3", value: "Value1", count: 9}]}]}]}, {field: "pivotvalue0", value: "222222222", count: 23, pivot: [{field: "pivotvalue1", value: "Y", count: 23, pivot: [{field: "pivotvalue2", value: "Header1", count: 12, pivot: [{field: "pivotvalue3", value: "Value2", count: 12}]}, {field: "pivotvalue2", value: "Header2", count: 11, pivot: [{field: "pivotvalue3", value: "Value2", count: 11}]}]}]}]

// demo
console .log (convert (topLevelObjects))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**`gather`** is a fairly generic helper function to recursively collect the results of applying a function to each node.  The initial parameter `prop` is used for the property name of the node that holds the deeper level of the tree (most commonly `'children'`, here `'pivot'`.)  The second parameter is a function whose result from each node will be collected into an array at the end.  And of course the third parameter is your tree object itself.  This is slight variant of my usual function here, as it flattens the result of each call before including it in the array.  This allows the function supplied to return an array with a single value or one with no values and for the output array to only include the real values.  (There are many alternative ways to do something like this if we wanted to use a more generic `gather`.)

We use `gather` in **`collectField`** to take all the associated `value` nodes when the `field` property matches the `name` supplied.  Note that we won't run this in the main recursive call of the function below.  These results will be appended later.  While it's quite possible to carry state information through deeply recursive calls, I prefer to avoid it if I can.  That means that for `pivotvalue2` and `pivotvalue3`, we actually do separate recursions.  Also note that you request `Set` in the output here, I use arrays for easier demo purposes.  But I note the two lines you can comment out to keep it an actual set.

The main function collects the fields specified into an object and then folds in a recursive call to the children in `pivot`, and then adds the two calls to `collectField`.

This is not ideal for performance, as we do the multiple recursive traversals of the input.  But it's simpler code and we could come back at it later if there was a measurable performance problem.

(I might look at another approach later on, as I have an idea, but no time right now.)

Comment: this looks great. Im going to see if I can work with it - maybe iteration variations of it. I will post back. Thank you for your effort!